# Populate form fields in a Modal with php

Tags: php, forms, modal-dialog

I am using ajax call on my #edit-cat (button to edit category) to get the response. The edit button also displays a bootstrap modal on click. The modal has a form with fields to edit the that particular category. So after the ajax call is done, **can I populate the modal form using php?**(I dnt want to use js or jquery for this if possible!)

**Note: I know it could be done in ajax success field using jquery, just need to know if its possible with php and how?**

my js file is like this:

```
$(document).on('click','#edit-cat', function(){
  var cat_edit_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
  $('add_cat').addClass('fadeOut');
  $.ajax({
   url: 'test.php',
   method: 'get',
   dataType: 'json',
   data: {'cat_edit_id':cat_edit_id },
   success:function(data){
   console.log(data);
   }
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You will populate your modal form with php inside test.php, receiving get or post values, filling them into test.php structure and bringing all frontend output of modal to your actual screen's body, appending that in the Ajax success.

Your JS

```
$(document).on('click','#edit-cat', function(){
  var cat_edit_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
  $('add_cat').addClass('fadeOut');
  $.ajax({
   url: 'test.php',
   method: 'get',
   dataType: 'json',
   data: {'cat_edit_id':cat_edit_id },
   success:function(data){
      $('body').html(data);
      //or
      $('body').prepend(data);
      //or
      $('body').append(data);
   }
 });
});
```

test.php:

```
<?php
      include("include/db_conn.php");
      include("include/functions.php");
      if(isset($_GET['cat_edit_id'])){
         $row = selectCategory($_GET['cat_edit_id']);
         $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($row);
         //inside include use $row as you want
         include("include/modals/category_modal.php");
       }

?>
```

Only asserts that your test.php are showing the html part of modal like you want, that ajax when returns will bring what's the link is showing.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, what you saying makes sense but could throw some light onto how to get the modal code as ajax response?

Comment: Look my edit, I thought you already understood. Avoid edit answers that you're not tested and validated by yourself with confidence.

Comment: Ok, so I tried it but the `$('body').html(data);` seems to remove all the markup from the <body> and replace it with just the modal markup. Searched a bit to target the `::before` pseudo class but jquery cant target what not already there.

Comment: need to use `prepend()` instead of `html()`. Thanks a lot for your help. Your answer got me thinking and helped me understand ajax functioning better.

Comment: I already did mate. But my reputation is below 15. you can call me a noob.